# Template spreadsheet's script authorization across instances?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a Google Web App; the app collects some data then creates a copy of a Google Spreadsheet template, configuring the new copy based on the collected data.  The template sheet includes a library we created.

Every user, for every copy of the template, needs to re-authorize permission for the included library, even though the library doesn't change.  This is really frustrating and annoying to the users.

In an ideal scenario users within our Goole Apps Domain shouldn't ever need to provide authorization.  In a less ideal, but better than current, scenario users would grant authorization to the master library once (or current version of the script) and then for all future copies of the template would not be prompted again.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Any way of just adding new sheets or data within the 1st one instead of creating entirely new spreadsheets on each web app submission?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Bryan's pertinent comment I'd suggest another workaround that should do the trick:

Instead of creating a new SS every time you could :

1. create a backup copy of the authorized SS with the same name
2. Clear the content of the authorized SS that is not part of the template ( ie keep format and other usefull headers / formulas)
3. rename this original SS with the name you would have given to the new SS

Doing so you use always the same document that is already authorized.

*That said, I agree with you that these authorization procedures are quite painful and that it should be handled differently in a domain (where "software people" are supposed to be trustful) and this has already been discussed with Google techs but they don't seem to be ready to change their position in that matter...*